# How to access exception/stacktrace in Velocity template resolved by web.xml's error-page?

Tags: exception, velocity, web.xml

I would like to print the cause of the HTTP Error 500 on my Velocity template but am having difficulty figuring out how this can be done.

My web.xml is configured with:

```
 <error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error/500</location>
 </error-page>
```

The location is backed by a Spring controller.  The 500.vm page is resolving as expected but how do I access the exception which resulted in this error page?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Is this an Avetti App? An http 500 is a 'catch all' type error that can't be determined by the application, so the server relays the message ("stuff is messed up").  This type of error usually happens when an application breaks or didn't properly handle an exception... so there is no exception to catch or present on the page.